# How much can MPI_Alltoall outperform MPI_Alltoallv?

Tags: mpi

I wonder what is the difference in terms of running time between executing the `MPI_Alltoallv` and `MPI_Alltoall` functions when the amount of transferred data is approximately the same? I couldn't find any such benchmark results. I am interested in large-scale instances, where tens of thousands or better hundreds of thousand of MPI processes are used and where these processes correspond to a substantial part of a given HPC system (considering at best some modern ones, such as BG/Q, Cray XC30, Cray XE6, ...).

Comment: If the amount of transferred data is going to be the same, why would you use alltoallv? Self-consistent MPI says alltoallv provides more flexibility so in no case should it outperform alltoall -- or else the library should simply make alltoall a special case of alltoallv.

Comment: If the amount of data is relatively large, it usually doesn't matter whether `MPI_Alltoall` or `MPI_Alltoallv` is being used. When the amount of data is relatively small, there are many efficient algorithms to implement the all-to-all with equal-sized chunks (i.e. `MPI_Alltoall`). What is "relatively small" and what is "relatively large" depends on the system and network architectures.

Comment: @RobLatham: My problem cannot be solved with MPI_Alltoall called only once, in contrast to MPI_Alltoallv. Maybe (I still don't know, had to be proved) it could be solved calling MPI_Alltoall multiple times (at least two times).

Comment: @HristoIliev: I was not sure, since I thought that some collectives are highly optimized on MPPs, but not all. I've read somewhere that MPI_Alltoallv is typically implemented using point-to-point operations and that users' implementations can even perform better than the implementation provided by the library.

Comment: Custom implementations rarely outperform vendors' solutions. But sometimes vendors are too lazy or too busy to test everything. For example, there was a performance regression in one of Open MPI's implementations of `MPI_ALLTOALLV` that I [reported](https://svn.open-mpi.org/trac/ompi/ticket/3079) almost three years ago together with a patch for it. And although it was dead trivial to fix, the fix never made it into 1.6 or 1.7. And to top it, this algorithm became the default one in 1.6 since it scales better (sans the performance regression).

Comment: I think you have one option here: implement it and try it out.  Pragmatically speaking, perhaps you will find once you instrument and profile your code at scale that alltoallv is not actually your performance bottelneck?   Also, bear in mind that there are two costs to collectives: the actual moving of data costs, which are highly optimized, and the synchronization costs: waiting for everyone to enter the collective.  non-blocking collectives help with the latter a bit, but now we are really out of scope for this question!

Comment: Alltoallv is actually my performance bottleneck, in the original algorithm it takes more than 95% of runtime for large-scale runs. Yes, I will implement it and try it out, however, it will cost some core-hours. That was why I asked first :). Anyway, thanks for comments...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Overview

One of the big advantages of MPI_Alltoall is that protocol decisions can be made quickly because they depend on a handful of scalars.  In contrast, if a library implementer wants to optimize MPI_Alltoallv, they have to scan four vectors to determine if, for example, the communication is nearly homogeneous, highly sparse, or some other pattern.

The other issue is that MPI_Alltoall can easily use the output buffer as scratch space because every process provides and consumes the same amount of data.  For MPI_Alltoallv, it's not practical to do all the bookkeeping, so any scratch space is going to be allocated.  I can't remember the specifics of this issue, but I think I've read it somewhere in the MPI canon.

## Implementation Skeletons

There are at least two special cases of alltoallv for which one can optimize better than the MPI library can:

1. Nearly homogeneous communication, i.e. the count vectors are nearly constant.  This can happen when you have a distributed array that doesn't divide evenly across the process grid.  In this case, you can:

   a. Pad your arrays and use MPI_Alltoall directly.

   b. Use MPI_Alltoall for the subset of processes that have homogeneous communication and either MPI_Alltoallv or a batch of Send-Recv for the remainder.  This works best if you can cache the associated communicators.  Using nonblocking communication should help too.

   c. Write your own implementation of Bruck that handles the cases where the count varies, which is likely at the end of your vector.  Having not done this myself, I don't know how difficult or worthwhile this one is.
2. Sparse communication, i.e. the count vector contains a large number of zeros.  For this case, just use a batch of nonblocking Send-Recv and Waitall, because that's likely the best the MPI library will ever do and doing it yourself allows you to tune the batch size if you want.

## Papers

[MPI on a Million Processors](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/papers/P1621A.pdf) describes the scalabillity issue associated with vector collectives.  Granted, you may not see the cost of scanning the vector arguments on most CPUs, but it is an O(n) problem that motivates implementers to not touch the vector arguments more than necessary.

[HykSort: a new variant of hypercube quicksort on distributed memory architectures](https://doi.org/10.1145/2464996.2465442) describes a custom implementation that performs much better than optimized libraries.  Such an optimization is rather difficult to implement inside of an MPI library, because it may be rather specialized.  (This reference is targeted at Hristo's comment, not your question, by the way.)

## Code

You can discover some interesting things by comparing the implementations of these operations in MPICH (https://github.com/pmodels/mpich/blob/main/src/mpi/coll/alltoall.c and https://github.com/pmodels/mpich/blob/main/src/mpi/coll/alltoallv.c).  Only MPI_Alltoall uses [Bruck's algorithm](http://authors.library.caltech.edu/12348/1/BRUieeetpds97.pdf) and pairwise exchange.  Similar conclusions can be drawn from the available options for `I_MPI_ADJUST_ALLTOALL` and `I_MPI_ADJUST_ALLTOALLV` on https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/528906.  Whether these limitations are fundamental or merely practical is left as an exercise for the reader.

## Practical Experience

When MPI_Alltoall on Blue Gene/P used DCMF_Alltoallv ([source code](https://github.com/pmodels/mpich/blob/55624189680931bebeb6f7a7ff46ee6b71139c31/src/mpid/dcmfd/src/coll/alltoall/alltoall_algorithms.c)), so there was no difference relative to MPI_Alltoallv, and the latter might have even been better since the application pre-populated the vector arguments.

I wrote a version of all-to-all exchange for Blue Gene/Q that was as fast as MPI_Alltoall.  My version was agnostic to constant versus vector arguments so this result implies that MPI_Alltoallv would perform similarly to MPI_Alltoall.  However, I can't find the code now to be absolutely sure of the details.

However, Blue Gene networks were rather special, particularly w.r.t. all-to-all, so the behavior on fat-tree or dragonly networks on systems where the CPU is much faster than the network will be quite different.

I suggest you write a benchmark and measure it where you intend to run your application.  Once you have some data, it will be much easier to figure out what optimizations may be missed.